# Retrieve input values from a part of the page

Tags: javascript

In a page, I have two divs and two buttons as below.

```
<div id="Sec-1">
    <input name="fullname" type="text">
</div>

<div id="Sec-2">
    <input name="fullname" type="text">
</div>

<button id="button-1" type="button" onclick="showValue('Sec-1')">Pass Value of Sce-1</button>
<button id="button-2" type="button" onclick="showValue('Sec-2')">Pass Value of Sec-2</button>
```

On click of the button 1, I need to create an object like `{fullname: "whatever user enters"}` taking from the div=Sec-1 and the same for the button 2 but from the div=Sec-2.

Both divs have same named input fields and I cannot add id for each input field. I also don't want to use form because there is a possibility of having these divs nested, so eventually it will be form in form.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function showValue(id) {
   const input = document.querySelector(`#${id} input[name='fullname']`);
   const object = { fullname: input.value };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, I have shorten my actual problem. As a result, it may not clear to you.

I need to pull the value that is defined in the name attribute. In other words, the script should pull the "fullname" from the code/DOM along with what user enters.

I am trying to pull it using querySelectAll (because there are more fields in actual code). It is returning everything but "fullname".

Comment: You get an inputs name attribute by just calling that, `<input>.name`. Are you going to have multiple inputs in `<div id="Sec-1">` or any other div section? if not the replace `const input with`, document.querySelector(`#${id} input`);
and then in the object, `{  fullname: input.name }`

Comment: 1. Yes, I will have more than one inputs in the each section.

2. I have used `document.querySelectorAll("#Sec-1 input")`. It gives me a NodeList. It has everything but the value of the name attribute.

Comment: If theres going to be multiple inputs in the divsections then you need to give a class to the inputs you want to acquire, `document.querySelectorAll` gives a nodelist, use `document.querySelector` to get the first element that passes the query. After you get that element just call .name on it.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I have used `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#Sec-1 input")).map (v => v.name)`. It yields the value that user entered, not the attribute value.